# Mysql query element groups separated by dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im currenty crwaling a website and saving to a DB all the images from a carousel.
each of this images have a position, link, image url, etc.

findle with all the info: [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3920b/2/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3920b/2/0) (thanks to Ollie Jones)

So de DB looks kinda like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
 ║id ║  element   ║  position   ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg   ║     date    ║
 ╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
 ║ 1 ║ foo        ║      1      ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 2 ║ foo        ║      2      ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 3 ║ foo        ║      3      ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 4 ║ foo        ║      4      ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 5 ║ foo        ║      5      ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 6 ║ foo        ║      6      ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 7 ║ foo        ║      1      ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║ 8 ║ foo        ║      2      ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║ 9 ║ foo        ║      3      ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║10 ║ foo        ║      4      ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║11 ║ foo        ║      5      ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║12 ║ foo        ║      6      ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║13 ║ foo        ║      1      ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║14 ║ foo        ║      2      ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║15 ║ foo        ║      3      ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║16 ║ foo        ║      4      ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║17 ║ foo        ║      5      ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║18 ║ foo        ║      6      ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║.. ║    ...     ║     ...     ║     ...     ║     ...     ║     ...     ║      ...    ║
 ╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

And then in my reports, I query the database to show me what element were present in the carousel with start date and end date, if there is a change in position, title, url of the link of jpg then it doest have to show me any range... for instance, the query of the DB before should look like:

```
 ╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
 ║element  ║  position ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg ║           date           ║
 ║═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
 ║ foo     ║      1    ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      2    ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      3    ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      4    ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      5    ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      6    ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

The above uses this query:

```
mysql_query("
 SELECT id, element, position, title, url_link, url_jpg, 
        (case when min(date) <> max(date) 
         then concat(min(date), ' to ', max(date)) 
         else min(date) end) as date
    FROM table 
   GROUP BY element, posistion, title, url_link, url_jpg 
   ORDER BY element, date ASC, position ASC
")
```

Now the problem is that when all elements change BUT one, like this:

new DB:

```
 ╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
 ║id ║  element   ║  position   ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg   ║     date    ║
 ╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
 ║ 1 ║ foo        ║      1      ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 2 ║ foo        ║      2      ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 3 ║ foo        ║      3      ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 4 ║ foo        ║      4      ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 5 ║ foo        ║      5      ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 6 ║ foo        ║      6      ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6     ║  20-12-2013 ║
 ║ 7 ║ foo        ║      1      ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║ 8 ║ foo        ║      2      ║  newtitle2  ║     url2    ║    jpg2     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║ 9 ║ foo        ║      3      ║  newtitle3  ║     url3    ║    jpg3     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║10 ║ foo        ║      4      ║  newtitle4  ║     url4    ║    jpg4     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║11 ║ foo        ║      5      ║  newtitle5  ║     url5    ║    jpg5     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║12 ║ foo        ║      6      ║  newtitle6  ║     url6    ║    jpg6     ║  21-12-2013 ║
 ║13 ║ foo        ║      1      ║     title1  ║     url1    ║    jpg1     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║14 ║ foo        ║      2      ║  newtitle2  ║     url2    ║    jpg2     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║15 ║ foo        ║      3      ║  newtitle3  ║     url3    ║    jpg3     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║16 ║ foo        ║      4      ║  newtitle4  ║     url4    ║    jpg4     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║17 ║ foo        ║      5      ║  newtitle5  ║     url5    ║    jpg5     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║18 ║ foo        ║      6      ║  newtitle6  ║     url6    ║    jpg6     ║  22-12-2013 ║
 ║.. ║    ...     ║     ...     ║     ...     ║     ...     ║     ...     ║      ...    ║
 ╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The same query will show me:

```
 ╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╗
 ║element  ║  position ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg ║   date      ║
 ║═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
 ║ foo     ║      2    ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2   ║ 20-12-2013  ║
 ║ foo     ║      3    ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3   ║ 20-12-2013  ║
 ║ foo     ║      4    ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4   ║ 20-12-2013  ║
 ║ foo     ║      5    ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5   ║ 20-12-2013  ║
 ║ foo     ║      6    ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6   ║ 20-12-2013  ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╝
 ╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
 ║element  ║  position ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg ║           date           ║
 ║═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
 ║ foo     ║      1    ║    title1   ║     url2    ║    jpg2   ║ 20-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
 ╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
 ║element  ║  position ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg ║           date           ║
 ║═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
 ║ foo     ║      2    ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      3    ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      4    ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      5    ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      6    ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

And I want it to show me this:

```
 ╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
 ║element  ║  position ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg ║  date      ║
 ║═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
 ║ foo     ║      1    ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1   ║ 20-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      2    ║    title2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2   ║ 20-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      3    ║    title3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3   ║ 20-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      4    ║    title4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4   ║ 20-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      5    ║    title5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5   ║ 20-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      6    ║    title6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6   ║ 20-12-2013 ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝

 ╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
 ║element  ║  position ║   title     ║  url_link   ║   url_jpg ║           date           ║
 ║═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
 ║ foo     ║      1    ║    title1   ║     url1    ║    jpg1   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      2    ║ newtitle2   ║     url2    ║    jpg2   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      3    ║ newtitle3   ║     url3    ║    jpg3   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      4    ║ newtitle4   ║     url4    ║    jpg4   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      5    ║ newtitle5   ║     url5    ║    jpg5   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ║ foo     ║      6    ║ newtitle6   ║     url6    ║    jpg6   ║ 21-12-2013 to 22-12-2013 ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

(To separate them into tables in the php file I make a new table when date changes)

So I have no idea how could I change the query so the element with title1 separates into the two tables since there was a change in the GROUP date. :(

Hope is well explain, this is really giving me a headache.
thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be much more helpfull if you had created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) instead the nice ascii formating.

Comment: Since you are grouping your data by `element, posistion, title, url_link, url_jpg` if you see the data you show it has two rows within this group (foo, 1, title1, url1, jpg1) which will separate your data because of your case statement. Maybe if you take out the title from the group it should give you your result. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Here's a fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3920b/2/0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are seeing is due to ORDERING problems with your resultset's date column. My Fiddle (here) uses actual DATE values, not dd-mm-yyyy values, because we want them to sort correctly. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3920b/4/0   Also, I'm using this

```
    ORDER BY element, MIN(date), MAX(date), position ASC
```

Notice that rows 1, 7, 13  of your second dataset will GROUP together into a single result row with a date range of 2013-12-20 to 2013-12-22.

There's a minor mistake in your SQL.. you don't want to

```
     SELECT id, ....
```

because it's not mentioned in your GROUP BY.  See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3920b/3/0

Comment: but title1 should be a single result for date day 20 and then second row from 21 to 22

Comment: @gepex, why? your the input rows for title1 all group together according to your query. I cannot tell from your data or your query what criterion should cause row 1 to group separately from rows 7 and 13.